# Spring JMS consumer concurrency-prototype scope bean needed

Tags: spring-jms

I have a Spring JMS consumer with a max of 2 concurrent consumers and minimum 1 consumer up all the time.

I  am creating bean and trying to send a notification to a 3rd party so here that bean is created in singleton scope, but I want to created 2 different objects for 2 different consumers.

To check if 2 different objects got created or single object shared by both consumers I am checking if object is `null` or not. If `null` then only it will be creating object otherwise no. So it only creating object only once.

I tried Prototype scope but its not working.

Please suggest?

Comment: I tried to update the grammar and punctuation to make your question more comprehensible, but it's still very unclear to me.

Comment: @JustinBertram
Currently in my case JMS consumer concurrency is more than 1. Spring boot JMS all consumers are using  same singleton bean created once, but in my case I want to create different objects for different consumers. Hence I tried prototype scope but its also not creating new object for new consumer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that; prototype scope simply means a new instance is created for each **reference**; even if a container's currency is > 1, it still only has a reference to a single listener instance.

You would have to create multiple containers (with concurrency=1) to get multiple instances.